# Code First Migrations - Update-database -script command generated SQL script not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have to created a database through Entity Framework 5 with the following model:

```
public class Post
{
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have added new property in `Post`

```
public string Abstract { get; set; }
```

then I have run

```
Add-Migration AddPostAbstract
```

which created the following class in my `Migrations` folder, after that I have modified this file by adding one more SQL statement

```
//201308300714477_AddPostAbstract.cs
public override void Up()
{
                AddColumn("dbo.Posts", "Abstract", c => c.String());
                Sql("UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.Posts", "Abstract");
}
```

After that I have executed this command

```
Update-Database –Verbose
```

which updated my database and also returned this SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] ADD [Abstract] [nvarchar](max)
UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL
```

Now I have deleted `Abstract` column from table and tried to execute the above query manually in SQL at that time it show me following error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'Abstract'.

My question is  why this query is not executed in SQL even this query is generated through migration?

Or is there any way to run such multiple query through migration generated script.

Comment: I've answered it here correcly but it was deleted as i've answered it somewhere else at the same time. Silly rule.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014118/can-entity-framework-6-migrations-include-a-transaction-around-scripts/33827354#33827354

Comment: For situations like this, within the migration, I replace the SQL("...") with SQL("EXEC(...)"). This way, I SQL doesn't try to compile the line until it executes it.

Answer (score 12):

The `-Verbose` output just shows a summary of statements. If you run your command manually in SQL Server Management Studio then you need a `GO` between the two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] ADD [Abstract] [nvarchar](max)
GO
UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL
```

The quick fix is to do something like:

- update-database -script
- then use Sql Server management Studio to do the following search and replace in the generated script:

  - find what: `^{:b*}{{INSERT|UPDATE|SELECT|DELETE}.+}` (*this finds any CRUD statements*)
  - replace with: `\1GO\n\1\2\n` (*keep the indents, and add `GO` before any CRUD statements*)
  - Find options: Use regular expressions

But, note that `-Verbose` doesn't give you the output you want, you need the output from `-Script`, or you will be missing the inserted data for the `__MigrationHistory` history table which could cause your application to throw an error when it runs (see below for details).

**Details**

Your comment below about the information on the [MSDN Code First Migrations page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621) is interesting. The page actually states (under the section *"Getting a SQL Script"*)

> Run the Update-Database command but this time specify the –Script flag

If you do this you will see something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Posts] ADD [Abstract] [nvarchar](max)
UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL
INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory] ([MigrationId], [Model], [ProductVersion]) VALUES ( ...
```

The `INSERT` is important - this is how your EF in your application will know it is using the latest db version (and will therefore run instead of showing you an error). But, it is still missing that GO command. SQL server therefore tries to compile the 3 lines as a single batch and fails.

After adding the `GO` statements you need, you can still run this in a single transaction by surrounding it with:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
   --Your migration code, with GO statements
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

If you are frustrated because you are generating large scripts, putting a `GO` at the end of any `ALTER TABLE` line is trivial with replace in SSMS, which would be something like the one at the top of this answer

Comment: please look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621 this under "Getting a SQL Script" they has mention generated ready for us to view or save,is there any other possible way to achieve this without using "GO".

Comment: Did you use the `–Script ` flag, or just `-Verbose`? `-Script` is the recommended way to get the update script you can then run, `-verbose` just shows a command summary.

Comment: The answer over here is worth reading too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12495077/150342

Comment: Yup, same summary: migrations issue each statement as a batch, and the `-script` output forgets to split the batches up. regex transformation to add `GO` to the script output before all data `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` will fix it.