# Can Entity Framework 6 migrations include a transaction around scripts?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Very simple question, i am using migrations in entity framework 6, and like the command

```
update-database -script
```

But is there a way of generating the script but have it wrapped with a transaction?

Problem is that if the script fails, i have to unpick it

Comment: You could take this approach, although tedious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528376/code-first-migrations-update-database-script-command-generated-sql-script-not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I'm using only on release mode to generate the scripts:

```
public class MigrationScriptBuilder : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
#if !DEBUG
    protected override void Generate(SqlOperation sqlOperation)
    {
        Statement("GO");

        base.Generate(sqlOperation);

        Statement("GO");
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
    {
        yield return new MigrationStatement {Sql = "BEGIN TRAN"};

        foreach (var migrationStatement in base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken))
        {
            yield return migrationStatement;
        }

        yield return new MigrationStatement {Sql = "COMMIT TRAN"};
    }
#endif
}
```

You should wire that in your `DatabaseMigrationsConfiguration`. Example:

```
public sealed class DatabaseMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseContext>
{
    public DatabaseMigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MigrationScriptBuilder());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using this?  Where do i put this?  Can you run ```update-database -script``` and it generates the script with a transaction wrapped around?

Comment: sorry, i've added the where.

Comment: Note, this answer doesn't handle statements where `SuppressTransaction` is `true`, but they're rare, so it probably won't matter in practice.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're doing it only for release and not for debug?

Comment: It does not work in the Visual Studio console without -script

Comment: For any googlers who landed here, the efcore solution is a bit different, see the bottom of this link for a solution. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22613