# Wrapping EF Migrations in transaction

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have previously used DbUp for database migrations.  One of the features that I liked was that it could wrap all of the migration scripts in a single transaction.  So if any of the migration scripts failed, any previously executed migration scripts would be rolled back.

Can Entity Framework 6 wrap all migrations with a single transaction?

Comment: What made you think EF6 does not wrap all migrations in a single transaction?

Comment: I've never seen any definitive documentation that they run in transactions. If you generate a script, it definitely does not. So while individual migrations may be transactional (not even sure about that see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6322)), running them all in a batch may require something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014118/can-entity-framework-6-migrations-include-a-transaction-around-scripts).

Comment: Also, this issue can be mitigated because you can rollback by changing the TargetMigration. Not something I would recommend for PROD.

Comment: When you execute your migration scripts, do you wrap them in a transaction yourself?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this. No EF core does not wrap them in transactions