# EF code-first migrations not in batches

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a long migration script to execute, beginning from the initial migration, that was generated by VS/package-manager using `update-database -script`. It doesn't seem to automatically separate the script into batches so that I can easily execute it in sql management studio. Is there a way to do this, or are we expected to insert dozens of `go` manaully?

Comment: If you are doing this because of the "should be the first statement in a batch file" error, then you can get around it by using `EXEC` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164640/150342

Comment: I tried that method but seeing as the script is so long I'd have to go around escpaing the single quotes, it would be as laborious as inserting `go` after each batch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919216/dbmigration-sql-method-can-i-use-the-suppresstransaction-parameter-safely