# DbMigration.Sql method: can I use the "suppressTransaction" parameter safely?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When I want to create or alter stored procedures and views, I [avoid the "should be the first statement in a batch file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25164640/150342) error by putting the sql inside an `EXEC` statement like this:

```
Sql(EXEC('Alter View dbo.Foos As etc'))
```

This is all very well, but it does mean I have to escape apostrophes all the time.

I recently realised that the [DbMigration.Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method takes a boolean parameter named `suppressTransaction`. It is described like this in the documentation:

> A value indicating if the SQL should be executed outside of the
>   transaction being used for the migration process.

so I tested it out without using `EXEC` :

e.g. `Sql('Create View dbo.Foos As etc', true);`

It worked, but my concern is this. What if I make a mistake somewhere else in my migrations? I assume everything else gets rolled back but this Sql doesn't. Could I end up with the database in an indeterminate state? If that is true what use is this parameter?