# SQL Script executed from resource throws errors on Entity Framework 6 Code First Migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In my project I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First to connect with database. My solution contains two projects - DAL and Resources. DAL serves as Data Access Layer, while Resources is a library with, well, resources, like images or strings. In this project I've put 4 SQL Scripts - `CREATE_VIEWS.SQL`, `DROP_VIEWS.SQL`, `CREATE_PROCS.SQL` and `DROP_PROCS.SQL`.

In my first migration I want to execute `CREATE_X.SQL` scripts in `Up()` and `DROP_X.SQL` in `Down()`.
Here's a part of my `CREATE_VIEWS.SQL` script:

```
---------------------------------------------------- 
--         Copyright © 2017 Jan Bońkowski         -- 
---------------------------------------------------- 
GO 
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSomeView] 
AS 
SELECT  
    [dbo].[Activities].[ActivityId],
    ...
FROM [dbo].[Activities] 
INNER JOIN ... 

GO 
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSomeView2] AS 
SELECT  
    [dbo].[Activities].[ActivityId],
    ... 
FROM [dbo].[Activities] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Teachers] ON ...
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ActivityPrototypes] ... ;

...
GO
```

And my `CREATE_PROCS.SQL` script

```
----------------------------------------------------
--         Copyright © 2017 Jan Bońkowski         --
----------------------------------------------------
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSomeProc1]
    @StudentId INT,
    @Result BIT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0
    SELECT 
        @Count = COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
    WHERE [dbo].[AspNetUsers].[Id] = @StudentId
    IF (@Count > 0)
        SET @Result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 0
END

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSomeProc2]
    @TeacherId INT,
    @Result BIT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0
    SELECT 
        @Count = COUNT(*)
    FROM ...
    IF (@Count > 0)
        SET @Result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 0
END

...
GO
```

Overall schematic of both scripts are:

```
GO
CREATE VIEW/PROC

GO
CREATE VIEW/PROC
```

etc

Those scripts are embedded in Resources project as a File resource with `Build Action` set to `Content`. In my migration I try to call them:

```
Sql(EnrollmentSystem.Resources.Properties.Resources.CREATE_VIEWS);
Sql(EnrollmentSystem.Resources.Properties.Resources.CREATE_PROC);
```

at the end of `Up()` method, but I receive errors after `update-database`:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
Incorrect syntax near GO
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me with this issue. Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: Remove the first `GO`

Comment: @Sami tried, nothing changes

Comment: Try to use `Transaction` with `TRY CATCH`

Comment: @Sami where should I put the transaction and Try-catch structure?

Comment: See [BEGIN TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) and [TRY...CATCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Comment: @Sami wrapped entire script in transaction and still nothing

Comment: Basic issue is 'GO' is not a TSQL command, it is for tooling. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162187/entity-framework-how-to-create-sql-script-with-go-statements) for similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new, empty line after GO:

```
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSomeView] 
AS
```